# Android - Stack Overflow error / having trouble understand this DDM

Tags: android, stack-overflow, drawable

I am getting this error on my DDM. I am having trouble understand what it means. Something with an image I believe.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <!-- Row 1 = just the text of livefeedr, late a picture -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:src="@drawable/topbar" />

    <!-- Row 2 = 2 buttons. Each one take half the screen -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/createFeedButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/createfeed_button" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/myFeedsButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/myfeeds_button" >
        </Button>
    </TableRow>

    <!-- Row3 = 2 buttons -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchFeedButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/findfeed_button" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/settings_button">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>

    <!-- Row 4 - the upcoming stuff is here -->

</TableLayout>
```

Error message:

```
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ravebox.dev.livefeedr/ravebox.dev.livefeedr.LiveFeedrHomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:212)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at ravebox.dev.livefeedr.LiveFeedrHomeActivity.onCreate(LiveFeedrHomeActivity.java:32)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    ... 11 more
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    ... 23 more
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114): Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.indexOfStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:274)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.access$000(StateListDrawable.java:253)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange(StateListDrawable.java:95)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:306)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:70)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:749)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1767)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:588)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1767)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:588)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1767)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:588)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
12-03 16:41:36.090: E/AndroidRuntime(22114):    at android.graphics
```

Comment: Could you add the XML files for your layout and your StateListDrawable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout, you have the imageview in the TableLayout, but not in a TableRow.  I believe that the only thing that can go inside a TableLayout is a TableRow.  Wrap the ImageView in a TableRow, or move the Imageview outside the TableLayout and wrap the whole thing in a LinearLayout.